# How to run a command when running a tmux socket session?

Tags: tmux

So, let's say for example, I need to run a tmux socket between two users that runs

`echo foo`

To make this run on a normal tmux, it'd be best to do `tmux new -d -s Foo "echo foo"`

However, when running tmux using -S, I can't seem to find a way to automatically run a command as the session starts. Let's say our path is /home/user/tmux

I'd run `tmux -S /home/user/tmux`, and then on another account `tmux -S /home/user/tmux attach`. However, this doesn't leave an opportunity to specify a starting command. Any way I could do this?

Thanks.

Comment: You may want to take a look at this answer http://superuser.com/a/492549 ?

Answer (score 3):

So one approach is to spawn a new window and then attach:

```
tmux -S /tmp/socket new-window -n vi /usr/bin/vi
tmux -S /tmp/socket attach
```

So the client can create a new window and then connect to it.

However, I suspect that a tmux session might not be doing what you want it to do.

The reason that `attach` has no command is because a session represents a view what is currently seen on the screen, which is shared between all connected clients. So attaching with a command is a little weird. All clients will view the same thing, and the `new-window` call will change the view for all attached clients.

If you want to share a collection of windows (e.g views of running programs), but have each client have a distinct view then you need to create sessions. You can use the `-t` argument to `new-session` to make a session that shares its windows with another session. Apparently you can't use `-t` together with a command for the new session, which is actually a valid use case, so you end up using the `-d` flag and then spawning the command. To make things even more irritating it would appear that `new-window` lacks a session argument, so you instead rely on the order that things are called!

```
tmux -S /tmp/socket new-session -s base  # run once

# For each client
tmux -S /tmp/socket new-session -t client-view -d 
tmux -S /tmp/socket new-window /usr/bin/vi
tmux -S /tmp/socket attach -t client-view
```

This is all a bit of kludge put I have managed to use this sort of approach effectively for a number of years. (Each of my terminal windows is a distinct view into a shared tmux session).

You might be interested in this script https://github.com/rainerborene/tmx/blob/master/tmx that wraps all of this up into a single shell script.

Comment: All the `tmuxlib` python library might be of tangential interest for you if you are trying to do complicated things with tmux.